# product additional images right to the product image in opencart 2.0

Tags: css

I want to place additional images of products when open a product right to the product image as in default opencart 2.0.1.1 theme it is below the product image How to do it.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define a class named "image1" for the first `<li></li>` in your `<ul></ul>` class thumbnails. Give width 50% to both the divs named "col-sm-4" for product images and "col-sm-8" for product name and description. Remove `float: left` from `.thumbnails .image-additional` in stylesheet.css and define margin to 80%. Then, define a new class like this:

```
.thumbnails .image1 {
    width:70%;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
Go to catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl
Actually the code will be like this 
From line No 24
          <?php if ($thumb || $images) { ?>
          <ul class="thumbnails">
         <?php if ($thumb) { ?>
            <li><a class="thumbnail" href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumb;  ?>"   title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" /></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($images) { ?>
            <?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
            <li class="image-additional"><a class="thumbnail" href="<?php echo $image['popup']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>"> <img src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" /></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
**Replace 25 line to 35 line like this**
<?php if ($thumb || $images) { ?>
          <ul class="thumbnails">
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9">
 <?php if ($thumb) { ?>
            <li><a class="thumbnail" href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumb;  ?>"  id="zoom_01" data-zoom-image="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" /></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
<?php if ($images) { ?>
            <?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
            <li class="image-additional"><a class="thumbnail" href="<?php echo $image['popup']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>"> <img src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" /></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
</div>
    </div>
```